# 'getElement(s)By' in the PHP class SimpleXML like in PHP-DomDocument?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I have made a application using DomDocument & SimpleXML, but the server doesn't support DomDocument (Only SimpleXML). Now I am rewriting it, but there aren't any functions in SimpleXML like "getElementsByTagName" and "getElementById" (I only need those 2). I have searched a lot on php.net & google.com, but can't find one.

I am not that good to write my own. So, does anyone know a alternative/function/tip/script for me? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the server doesn't support the DOM extension? That would be a rather strange choice by the service provider since SimpleXML/DOM use the same underlying XML library. Neither are to be confused with the DOMXML extension for PHP 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Happily, if SimpleXML doesn't support those DOM-methods, it supports XPath, with the [**`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method.

And searching by tag name or id, with an XPath query, shouldn't be too hard.

I suppose queries like theses should do the trick :

- search by id : `//*[@id='VALUE']`
- search by tag name : `//TAG_NAME`

---

For example, with the following portion of XML and code to load it :

```
$str = <<<STR
<xml>
    <a id="plop">test id</a>
    <b>hello</b>
    <a>a again</a>
</xml>
STR;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

You could find one element by its `id="plop"` with something like this :

```
$id = $xml->xpath("//*[@id='plop']");
var_dump($id);
```

And search for all `<a>` tags with that :

```
$as = $xml->xpath("//a");
var_dump($as);
```

And the output would be the following one :

```
array
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string 'plop' (length=4)
      string 'test id' (length=7)

array
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string 'plop' (length=4)
      string 'test id' (length=7)
  1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
      string 'a again' (length=7)
```

Comment: additionally you can use the Selector Gadget to help you with those xpath queries: http://www.selectorgadget.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath. http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: This low-generosity answer should have been a comment under the question.