# Display specific SimpleXML record with URL parameter

Tags: php, html, simplexml

I've got a pretty simple XML file that I'd like to parse based on the URL parameter. So far, I'm grabbing the ID parameter with PHP with `$projid = $_GET["id"];` however using that in a meaningful way to only display a specific matching XML record with that ID is eluding me.

This is my example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<projects>
<project id="1">
    <id>1</id>
    <name>First project</name>
    <description>This is the description of the project</description>
</project>
<project id="2">
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Second project</name>
    <description>This is the description of the project</description>
</project>
</projects>
```

I am thus far, unsure if I can access a specific project record using the attribute id or the actual child `<id></id>` field. I am open to either, whichever is easiest and cleaner.

In short: by accessing url.com/projects.php?id=1, the page will display the contents of project 1 from the XML file. Any help would be grand.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['getElement(s)By' in the PHP class SimpleXML like in PHP-DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442096/getelementsby-in-the-php-class-simplexml-like-in-php-domdocument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple XPath query will do that job:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('yourfile.xml');

$xpath = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
$queryResult = $xpath->query('//projects/project[@id = "$id"]');

foreach($queryResult as $result){
    echo $result->textContent;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error, however, this is also not outputting anything.

Comment: And you are using a valid id and xml?

Comment: The entirety of my working XML file is above, I'm loading projects.xml instead of 'yourfile' and this is the URL in my bar: /project.html?id=1

Comment: I missed 1 level of project, updated

Comment: My apologies- I'm not seeing any code difference.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to save. Try this, I'll make a codepad example

Comment: I made a codepad example: http://codepad.org/shI90ILX